# Is it possible for an app to have access to sound being played in the background of another app on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, audio

Been working with some friends on some possible app ideas. I was wondering if given IOS 8.4 an app could access to the sound that was currently being played on the device and if so how would this be done.

Answer (score 1):

Yup you can do that, but there are some restrictions in it, you will get the information of currently played background music only if the other app which is playing the sound, is playing the sound with iPod library.

you can get the information with the help of `MPMusicPlayerController` like this

```
MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer().nowPlaying()
```